# SQL Query Interrogation Issue

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

This is my query:

```
SELECT f.FieldID,fd.FieldName, p.ProductID,pd.ProductName, p.Price,p.Stoc, p.IsActive,TextValue
FROM products_products p
LEFT OUTER JOIN products_products_details pd
on pd.ProductID = p.ProductID
LEFT OUTER JOIN fld_chosenvalues f
on f.ProductID = p.ProductID
INNER JOIN fld_fields_details fd
ON f.FieldID = fd.FieldID
WHERE  pd.Locale = "ro-RO" and fd.Locale = "ro-RO"
```

In the image below , you can see the result of the query : 
[image]

The problem is that I want to put the "Volum", the "Tip inchidere", the "Amabalare paiet", the "Ambalare bax" as a column and assign it the value "212ml"...
you can see in the image below what exactly i want :

[image]

I apologize for the images, but I didnt know any other ways to explain that. Thx

This is the query with pivot, obviously is not working :

```
SELECT f.FieldID,fd.FieldName, p.ProductID,pd.ProductName, p.Price,p.Stoc, p.IsActive,TextValue
FROM products_products p
LEFT OUTER JOIN products_products_details pd
on pd.ProductID = p.ProductID
LEFT OUTER JOIN fld_chosenvalues f
on f.ProductID = p.ProductID
INNER JOIN fld_fields_details fd
ON f.FieldID = fd.FIeldID
PIVOT
(
    FOR [f.FieldName] IN (['Volum'], ['Tip inchidere'], ['Amabalare palet'], ['Ambalare bax'])
) as pvt;
WHERE  pd.Locale = "ro-RO" and fd.Locale = "ro-RO"
```

Comment: This is called "pivoting". Some databases have built-in functions for this, some require you to do extra work in the query. Please specify the RDBMS so we can give you an appropriate answer.

Comment: @Barmar looks like the screenshot is phpMyAdmin/MySQL to me

Comment: yes it is in phpmyadmin. if you want I can give you pictures from the structure

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: this is a first time when i header about pivot, so i tried it, i updated my post, please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT 
    p.ProductID,
    pd.ProductName,
    SUM(p.Price) AS Price,
    SUM(p.Stoc) AS Stoc,
    p.IsActive,
    MAX(CASE WHEN fd.FieldName='Volum' THEN TextValue ELSE NULL END) AS Volum,
    MAX(CASE WHEN fd.FieldName='Tip inchidere' THEN TextValue ELSE NULL END) AS TipInchidere,  
    MAX(CASE WHEN fd.FieldName='Amabalare paiet' THEN TextValue ELSE NULL END) AS AmabalarePaiet,
    MAX(CASE WHEN fd.FieldName='Ambalare bax' THEN TextValue ELSE NULL END) AS Ambalarebax
FROM 
    products_products p
    LEFT JOIN products_products_details pd
        on pd.ProductID = p.ProductID
    LEFT JOIN fld_chosenvalues f
        on f.ProductID = p.ProductID
    INNER JOIN fld_fields_details fd
        ON f.FieldID = fd.FieldID
WHERE  
    pd.Locale = 'ro-RO' 
    and fd.Locale = 'ro-RO'
GROUP BY
    p.ProductID,
    pd.ProductName,
    p.IsActive
```

Comment: thx, for helping me . it works, but not 100% Im getting null values, where it should be values from the "Volum", etc

Comment: now i saw that , you have some spelling mistakes, but it works. thx man i really appreciate it :)

Comment: @Chester : Np. Glad to help

Comment: one question: what is the role of MAX before case ?

Comment: @Chester : Because of the group by. If there would be a case where one `FieldName` that would result in more `TextValue`s then it would pick the max of that `TextValue`